# How to use dompdf on Laravel 7 correctly?

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I am using barryvdh dompdf for my project, I am also new with laravel framework. I am trying to generate a pdf based on a query that will return one row. The error message is: "Trying to get property 'schedule_date' of non-object".

This is my function in my controller:

```
public function downloadPAasPDF($id)
    {
        $decoded_id = base64_decode($id);

            $data = DB::select('SELECT
             p.appointment_id, 
             d.schedule_date,
             d.time_start,
             d.time_end,
             o.oncology_name,
             pt.procedure_name
            , CONCAT(u1.first_name," ",u1.last_name) AS doctor, CONCAT(u2.first_name," ",u2.last_name) AS patient FROM doctor_schedule d
            LEFT JOIN patient_appointment p ON d.schedule_id = p.schedule_id
            LEFT JOIN users u1 ON u1.id = d.user_id
            LEFT JOIN users u2 ON u2.id = p.user_id
            LEFT JOIN oncology o ON p.oncology_id = o.oncology_id
            LEFT JOIN procedure_type pt ON p.procedure_id = pt.procedure_id
            WHERE p.appointment_id = '.$decoded_id.';');

            $pdf = PDF::loadView('Appointments.PatientAppointmentPDF', ['data' => $data]);
            return $pdf->download('Appointment.pdf');
    }
```

And this is my view:

```
 <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                        <th style="font-size:21px;">Reference No. {{preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9. ]/', '',$data->schedule_date)}}{{$data->appointment_id}} </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-size:23px;width:606px;height:46px;">Patient Name: {{$data->patient}}</td>
                            <td>Date: {{ date_format(date_create($data->schedule_date), 'm-d-Y') }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="width:1050px;">
                            <td style="width:345px;">Time Start: {{ date('g:i A',strtotime($data->time_start)) }}</td>
                            <td>Time End: {{date('g:i A',strtotime($data->time_end))}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="width:1050px;height:-118px;">
                            <td style="width:321px;height:98px;">Oncology: {{$data->oncology_name}}</td>
                            <td>Procedure: {{$data->procedure_name}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="width:1050px;height:-118px;">
                            <td style="width:321px;height:98px;font-size:20px;">Doctor: {{$data->doctor}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: I guess $data is an array not object.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte also tried array($data) can't get it to work

Comment: What's the result of `var_dump($data);` ?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte it's an array of the row that I want to pass to my view

Comment: before using PDF::loadView(), try to check if html is created properly without errors, `$view = view('Appointments.PatientAppointmentPDF', ['data' => $data]);
return $view->render();` tell what do you get result for this, do you get html of the pdf you want to show

Comment: @bhucho I removed the two lines of codes at the end of the function, and replaced it with your suggested code I still got the same eerror.

Comment: it is for that purpose only to tell that the view has error, try to do `dd($data)` inside your view and check if the object has the properties at the places you want it to have

Comment: @bhucho I tried to putting a foreach in my view and it rendered the correct output with your suggested code so I tried on the loadView and now it won't output anything it says "Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded"

Comment: how much data is there is $data variable, is your view quite big?

Comment: @bhucho like how many columns my query produce? well my view is only that table with a png on top that I didn't include in this post.

Comment: I mean how many keys are there in foreach or how may time it iterates like 1000 or more times with a lot of data for each loop

Comment: @bhucho Ohh just one time this is only for a single row

Comment: though it should not happen but you can exceed time limit to 300sec for that controller add this line in the controller at beginning `set_time_limit(300);`, though it is not a good technique, it is for debug also try to check from network tab how much time it consumes

Comment: also are you using development server or apache server(in case of windows xampp server)

Comment: @bhucho should I put it below the use lines before the main function of the controller? yeah I read about it too that php artisan is slow. But thank you for your help!

Comment: it is not about slow it is doing its best with limited resources is in the same thread, but production(apache,nginx) has more resources provided has a separate thread, this should give you time set_time_limit(300); for pdf rendering

Answer (score -1):

Here there are several things to keep in mind, the problem is possible that the query is not returning a result, first you should query directly by inserting that statement in the database manager (navicat or postgresql or phpmyadmin) to avoid errors in the query and verify that returns some tuple, second, you should somewhere in the code verify if the query returns any result, that is, if $data is not null or if it exists for validation reasons in your system and if there are no results, notify the user, on the other side I don't understand why you decode from base64? I imagine that the parameter is base64 encoded but I don't know why? any security reason? although occultism is not security... but it could be that in the decoding process you did not obtain the expected result... last but not least I do not remember if it is necessary in the query to add the ; in the case of this type of query with query builder...
PD: You could use phpstorm and install the debug to follow the process step by step. But I guess the problem is in the query.